# Proving linear map is ortogonal if only if it is an isometry

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(V, \langle.,.\rangle)$ be a Euclidean space.

How do I prove that a linear map $T: V \rightarrow V$ is orthogonal if and only if it is distance preserving (isometry), i.e $d(a,b) = d(T(a), T(b))$ for all $a,b \in V$

So far I have the Cauchy- Schwarz inequality to work with and the triangle inequality.
$d(x,z)≤d(x,y)+d(y, z)$ where $d(x,y)=\left\langle x-y, x-y\right\rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}$

I know an orthgonal linear map/matrix means $A^T*A=I$ but I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Is $V$ a real vector space or a complex vector space?

Comment: Doesn't actually say, but I think we assume everything is for a real vector space

Comment: As a side note: If $T : V \rightarrow V$ is distance preserving and $T(0)=0$, then it is also true that $T$ is linear. If $T(0) \ne 0$, then $T(x) = Ux+T(0)$ where $U$ is linear and orthogonal.

Comment: Still not too sure what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ preserves the distances, $\| A(x+y)\|^2=\|x+y\|^2$ i.e
$<A(x)+A(y),A(x)+A(y)>=<x+y,x+y>$ i.e $<A(x),A(x)>+2<A(x),A(y)>+<A(y),A(y)>=<x,x>+2<x,y>+<y,y>$. Since $A$ preserves the distances, $<A(x),A(x)>=<x,x>$ and $<A(y),A(y)>=<y,y>$ thus $<A(x),A(y)>=<x,y>$

Comment: Use `\langle' and '\rangle' to produce $\langle$ and $\rangle$ as opposed to $<$ and $>$.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without using the matrix form and using T and d(x,y)...

Comment: How does the last line show A is orthogonal?